# Passing reference to javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-9

Consider a non-fx existing application, let's call it `Business`.

`Business` exposes a `Model` object, which in turn exposes some properties. `Model` also accepts  listeners to those properties.

My question is about **adding**  JavaFx gui to such application. The `GuiApp` obviously extends `javafx.application.Application` and will need a reference to a `Model` object.

Searching for a solution for passing a non-String parameter to `GuiApp` I found several different approaches:

- Static approach :  for example have `Business` initialize a static reference to `Model` in `GuiApp`. One example of the use of statics can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25909862/3992939) .
- JavaFx  9 approach:  as demonstrated  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370465/3992939) you can launch JavaFx application without extending `Application`.
- Change workflow approach:  change the existing workflow to have `GuiApp`  initialize `BusinessApp` . One example of such workflow can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40793821/3992939).

Are there another viable approaches ? Best practice ?

Comment: hmm ... where's my earlier comment? Maybe not sent, not yet enough coffee ;) So here we go again: why do you have 2 classes of type Application (or what's businessApp?) Anyway, sounds like too much coupling: let Model live stand-alone and pass it around.

Comment: @kleopatra    I am sorry if I did not clarify well: only gui class extends `Application`. Gui class needs a reference of the `Model`, and so does `BusinessApp`. I will change the name of `BusinessApp` , it may be misleading.

Comment: okay, where/how does Business live?

Comment: @kleopatra I am trying to understand the reasonable scope of possibilities. For the sake of this small study we can assume both `Business` and `GuiApp` share the same windows machine.

Comment: @isnot2bad  Thanks for the comment. In regards to : "in the answer to your similar question" the posted link does not post to my question.

Comment: As I alread tried to say in the answer to a similar question (stackoverflow.com/questions/24611789/…), I don't see the needs of your Business application to 'launch' a JavaFx application. This smells like bad design. Instead, put common code into a library and reuse it from both applications.

Comment: @c0der you are right - sorry! I've changed my comment to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to demonstrate some different approaches for passing a reference between a java program, and a java-fx program. 
I post it in hope it will help some future readers having similar need. I also hope it may encourage other answers with additional solutions. 
The posted code should not be considered proper implementation, but rather a short code aiming to clarify the different approaches. For this purpose I'll introduce a simple listening interface :

```
interface Observe{ void update(int i); }
```

A java class, that represents an exiting business application :

```
public class JavaApp {

    private Observe observer;  private int counter = 0;

    JavaApp(Observe observer){  //not null safe
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    void process() {            
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                observer.update(counter >=100 ? 0 : ++counter);
            }
        }, 1000,1000);
    }
}
```

A java-fx application that should be added to the existing business application, listen to it and serve as view:

```
public class JavaFxApp extends Application implements Observe{

    private Label label;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        label = new Label("waiting");
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override public void update(int i) {
        Platform.runLater(()-> label.setText(String.valueOf(i)));
    }
}
```

*How do we share a reference, in this case a reference to `Observe` instance, between the two applications ?*

**Approach 1: Consider the `start()` method as the entry point to the application** (see James_D [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40793821/3992939))
This is simple and straight forward if you want to tie the existing java application with java-fx  and use java-fx `Application` as the entry point:

```
public class JavaFxApp extends Application implements Observe{

    private Label label;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {  
        JavaApp main = new JavaApp(this);
        label = new Label("waiting");
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        new Thread(()-> { main.process();}).start(); //launch the business process
    }

    @Override   public void update(int i) {
        Platform.runLater(()-> label.setText(String.valueOf(i)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch();  }
}
```

**Approach 2: Use JavaFX 9 Platform#startup**
This is the best solution I found, when you **can not** use the `Application#start` method as the entry point to the application.
As demonstrated  in fabians [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370465/3992939), as off java-fx 9 you can launch without extending `Application`. All you have to do is modify the `main` of the java application:

```
public class JavaApp {

    private Observe observer;  private int counter = 0;

    JavaApp(Observe observer){//not null safe
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    void process() {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override   public void run() {
                observer.update(counter >=100 ? 0 : ++counter);
            }
        }, 1000,1000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaFxApp view = new JavaFxApp(); //initialize JavaFx application
        JavaApp main = new JavaApp(view);

        Platform.startup(() -> {//launch JavaFx application 

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            try {
                view.start(stage);
            } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        });

        main.process(); //run business process 
    }
}
```

**Approach 3: Use Static members**
For example introduce a static getter in the java-fx application :

```
public class JavaFxApp extends Application {

    private static Label label = new Label("waiting");

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {  
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static Observe getObserver() {
        return JavaFxApp::update;
    }

    private static void update(int i) {
        Platform.runLater(()-> label.setText(String.valueOf(i)));
    }
}
```

and use it in the java application:

```
public class JavaApp {

    private Observe observer;  private int counter = 0;

    JavaApp(Observe observer){//not null safe
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    void process() {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                observer.update(counter >=100 ? 0 : ++counter);
            }
        }, 1000,1000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Thread(()-> Application.launch(JavaFxApp.class)).start();
        Observe observer = JavaFxApp.getObserver(); //get static observer reference
        JavaApp main = new JavaApp(observer);
        main.process();
    }
}
```

A better approach to get a static reference might be (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25909862/3992939) answer) :

```
public class JavaFxApp extends Application implements Observe{

    private static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private static Observe observer = null;
    private Label label;

   @Override public void init() {
       observer = this;
       latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage){
        label = new Label("waiting");
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 100, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override public void update(int i) {
        Platform.runLater(()-> label.setText(String.valueOf(i)));
    }

    static Observe getObserver() {
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }

        return observer;
    }
}
```