# How do i start a JavaFX GUI in an own thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I have a Project, where I need to start a GUI but in another thread that is not my main thread.

-> The first main thread starts...

-> If it decides to show a GUI it starts my GUI.

-> All other calculations should still happen in the main thread.

What I mean with this is, that i can't, ounder no circumstance, start the gui in the main thread. And i need to be able to comunicate with my Controller (no controller in the sample). But when i do the normal: .. Start extends Application { .. approach, I cant communicate with the controller anymore because the thread is occupied. The code below should allow me to do everything I need to do, so I hope there is a way I can make it work.

The problem, why my code doesn't work is a Exception:

Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized

When calling Platform.runLater() .. in my GuiThread class.

Thanks four your help in advance.

My main class:

```
public class Start{
    private void start() {
        GuiThread thread = new GuiThread();
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("here continues the thread, while the GUI is shown");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Start main = new Start();
        main.start();
    }
}
```

My custom thread class, where my GUI should be started:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GuiThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        // Here i have objects i need to have in the controller

        // Then i have to start my GUI

        // When calling Platform.runLater()... this error shows : Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Group root;
            try {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                root = new Group();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);

                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myGui.fxml"));
                Node node = loader.load();

                // Controller stuff

                root.getChildren().add(node);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Just a sample FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label text="left" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label text="right" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: What happens if `Start` `extends` `Application`?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53003746/passing-reference-to-javafx-application-application)  relvant question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd start any additional threads from the `Application.init` or `Application.start` methods, but in your case this doesn't seem to be an option.

Starting with JavaFX 9 you could use [`Platform.startup`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#startup(java.lang.Runnable)) the first time you need access to JavaFX. After the `Runnable` passed to that method is executed you should be able to use `Platfrom.runLater` as you're used to.

Using this approach you need to make sure to shut when all other logic has completed and you're sure you don't need to display any GUI.

```
Platform.startup(() -> {
    Group root;
    try {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myGui.fxml"));
        Node node = loader.load();

        // Controller stuff

        root.getChildren().add(node);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnHidden(evt -> Platform.exit()); // make sure to completely shut down JavaFX when closing the window
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```